# Welcome email not received

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We are using onestepcheckout in our site.

When we try to place the order than we are unable to receive the welcome email. We are however getting the order email successfully.

Server configuration:

- PHP5.4
- Nginx
- Magento 1.9

Note: *We have setup the admin configuration for email perfectly in the Admin*

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you correctly assigned the email template in admin?

Comment: if you are using the onestepcheckout extension, you might check the custom controller for that login in checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Emails are not sent unless cron is running. This was a change in 1.9 and 1.14 as well.